# Re-sizing Child window using javascript jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am making a form submit with two parameters and response is opening in new window like

```
<html>
<a href="#" onclick="generateandpost()">Click Here</a>
<script>
function generateandpost(){

    var params = [
        'height='+screen.height,
        'width='+screen.width,
        'fullscreen=yes'
    ].join(',');

    var form = document.createElement("form");
    form.setAttribute("method", "post");
    form.setAttribute("target", "_blank");

    form.setAttribute("action", "http://myurl.com");
    // setting form target to a window named 'formresult'
    form.setAttribute("target", "formresult");
    var hiddenField = document.createElement("input");              

    var mapInput = document.createElement("input");
    mapInput.type = "hidden";
    mapInput.name = "empid";
    mapInput.value = '756746574';
    form.appendChild(mapInput);


    var mapInput1 = document.createElement("input");
    mapInput1.type = "hidden";
    mapInput1.name = "moduleid";
    mapInput1.value = '457646574';
    form.appendChild(mapInput1);
    document.body.appendChild(form);

    window.moveTo(0,0);
    window.resizeTo(screen.availWidth, screen.availHeight);
    form.submit();

}
</script>
</html>
```

When the target window is opening it is not maximized. I want maximized window should be open so I am using the `height` and `width` but target window is still opening in small window.

Please tell me what I am missing.

Comment: but when you try to do `window.resizeTo` you're actually trying to change your `parent` window

Comment: Agreed but is there any way to change the child window

Comment: where is your child window? where is window' `open` method call?

Comment: form.setAttribute("target", "_blank");    is opening the child window in IE

Comment: hmm , interesting.. i don't know how to control this new window in this case. i suggest you to use good old `window.open` method

Comment: It may happen due to cache also..search in google for window minimised cache problem..